# Android Room how to make a copy of an existing POJO entity and use DAO to save the copy in database

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, sql-insert

I want to make a copy of an existing POJO in the Room database. The database contains a one-to-one relationship between two entities: Person and Device.

The Person entity contains a primarykey(autogenerate = true) field, pId, which is also a foreign key in Device. I want the copy to have a new autogenerated pId, but the majority of the other columns will be the same.

I am thinking the following code might work, but is very cumbersome especially if I have lots of columns under Person and Device:

```
private suspend fun copyPersonWithDevice(personWithDevice: PersonWithDevice) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val personCopy = Person()
            val personCopyId = repository.insertPerson(personCopy)
            val deviceCopy = Device(pId = personCopyId)
            repository.insertDevice(deviceCopy)
            repository.updatePerson("iterate through columns other than pId, in person entity, e.g. personWithDevice.person.name, personWithDevice.person.age, etc.")
            repository.updateDevice("iterate through columns other than pId and dId, in device entity")
        }
    }
```

Is there a more logical way to make a copy of the POJO and insert into database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two general ways - to play with SQL-queries (as you've wrote it's a little bit "cumbersome") or manipulate with objects.

Let's look at second way for your use-case.
Let's say in your Dao you have next methods:

- insertPerson(person: Person): Long
- insertDevice(device: Device)
- getDeviceWithPersonId(personId: String): Device? // getting Device on foreign key since you have one-to-one relations

Then you can give a try with next code:

```
@Transaction
private suspend fun copyPersonWithDevice(person: Person) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val deviceForCopy = repository.getDeviceWithPersonId(person.pId)
        person.pId = 0 // <- That makes Room autogenerate primary id in the next line
        val personCopyId = repository.insertPerson(person) // <- new row added
        if (deviceForCopy != null) {
            deviceForCopy.personId = personCopyId // set foreign key with copied row's id
            deviceForCopy.id = 0 // <- That makes Room autogenerate primary id in the next line
            repository.insertDevice(deviceForCopy) // <- new row added  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sergiy tikhonov! This is method is better than using SQL queries. For those that are using immutable data class with val, instead of "person.pId = 0", use "val personCopy = person.copy(pId = 0)".